# Fail to print out the id number

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here are the code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
r = requests.get('http://zq.win007.com/big/League/2019-2020/31.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
league_table = soup.find('div', class_ = 'tdsolid')
for item in league_table.findAll('tr id'):
        print(item)
```

Expected Result:
1740522
1740525
1740529
1740528
1740527
1740530
1740521
1740526
1740524
1740523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the result is loaded by javascript and you cannot get the output by requests. Consider using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://zq.win007.com/big/League/2019-2020/31.html"

browser = webdriver.Chrome("YOUR CHROME DRIVER PATH")
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
league_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'tdlink lh17 fixedtable')
for item in league_table.findAll('tr'):
        print(item.get("id"))
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you Yash Shah. The code is fine. And i had one more question: how can i get the all the id via each round 1...38?

Comment: you then need to simulate clicks via selenium. every round has the same class

Comment: i added the code before soup.
 elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("lsm1")
 for e in elements:
     e.click()

but no any result